# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration after modifying XML

Tags: xml, eclipse, hibernate, exception

My project was working until that point when I tried to set the character encoding to UTF-8.
I added the `<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>` line to my `hibernate.cfg.xml`.
Now after a computer restart I'm getting this strange error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    at dal.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at dal.hibernate.HibernateDAOFactory.getSession(HibernateDAOFactory.java:25)
    at dal.hibernate.HibernateUserDAO.authenticate(HibernateUserDAO.java:23)
    at controller.servlet.LogIn.doPost(LogIn.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 22 more
```

The first four classes in the stack are my classes.

I see that the `new Configuration();` calling causes the error, but I have the necessary JAR-s in the WEB-INF/lib:

- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
- javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar

Here is the configuration XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/web_projekt</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">******</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="core/bean/tables.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Have you any idea what's the problem?

Comment: how is the project's dependencies managed? maven, buil path etc

Comment: Have you configured the `Deployment Assembly`

Comment: The JAR-s are managed simply by build path. I doesn't configured Deployment Assembly. The project was running perfectly -- until this point.

Comment: Did you save the files as UTF-8 (an option in your editor) or are they still in the ISO-xxxx format?

Comment: If it is a dynamic web project, `rt click on the project > properties > deployment assembly` then check whether hibernate core is checked there

Comment: No. The XML-s and the JSP files are all UTF-8, but the .java files are Cp1250. Could be that a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a dinamic web project. Only two source directories were in the Deployment Assembly's list: `/src` with `WEB_INF/classes` Deploy Path and `/WebContent` with `/` Deploy Path.